# Regarding Prestashop One page Super checkout by Knowband

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I just bought Presta Shop One page Super Checkout module from below link...

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/checkout-modules/18016-one-page-checkout-with-social-login-ship2pay.html

Can anybody help me to add a new field in it?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible by default to add a new field in this module, but you can add some HTML code for a new custom field by editing the tpl file(s) of this module. In that case you also need to handle the value provided in the field and save it to your database.

Alternatively, if there is a useless field in the address form then you can simply change its name to what ever you want.